# xsane doesn't work properly after upgrading to ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, scanner, epson, xsane

I own a Epson perfection 2480. It works like a charm on my laptop with ubuntu 14.04 (xsane 0.998) and with Vuescan on my desktop with ubuntu 16.04.
But on my desktop with ubuntu 16.04 and xsane 0.999, my scanner doesn't work properly anymore. 
You are warned, like it seems to have a lot of problems between xsane and ubuntu 16.04, don't upgrade before checking if your scanner still working.

That said, I m looking for any (free, Vuescan is expensive) solution to get my scanner working back with my desktop and ubuntu 16.04.

Thank you.

Comment: I noticed my scanner didn't work under 16.04 as well but I haven't used that functionality in a couple of years, just printing. You can downgrade xsane to version 0.998 and freeze the package there so the daily updates don't flip it back to 0.999. I had to do that with Conky and Nvidia.